# How to perform cleanup of individually allocated things cleanly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given is the following function:

```js
function createDir(): { path: string, x: number, y: number };
```

If the function is executed multiple times in a row we have this:

```js
const { path: path0 } = createDir();
/* ... do something here */
const { path: path1 } = createDir();
/* ... do something ELSE here */
const { path: path2 } = createDir();
/* ... do something completely else here */
const { path: path3 } = createDir();
/* ... and here is another code block */
```

What is the most TypeScriptish way to remove all directories at the end, even if one of the functions fails in between? It seems I have to use a `try/catch` here but how do I perform a cleanup in the `finally` block of a `try/catch`?

This solution looks unnecessarily complicated to me:

```js
let cleanup: string[] = [];
try {
    const { path: path0 } = createDir();
    /* ... do something here */
    cleanup.push(path0);
    const { path: path1 } = createDir();
    /* ... do something ELSE here */
    cleanup.push(path1);
    const { path: path2 } = createDir();
    /* ... do something completely else here */
    cleanup.push(path2);
    const { path: path3 } = createDir();
    /* ... and here is another code block */
    cleanup.push(path3);
} finally {
    for (const path of cleanup) {
        fs.rmSync(path, { recursive: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `cleanup`?

Comment: @DOZBORNE: `fs.rmSync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This solution looks unnecessarily complicated to me

I don't think it gets a *lot* more elegant, it's one of those cumbersome things by nature. You could have a function to do both the creation and the addition to the array. Also, don't forget to catch and either handle or suppress errors from the `rmSync` call at the end, so a failure on one doesn't prevent removing the others.

```typescipt
const cleanup: string[] = [];
const create = () => {
    const { path } = createDir();
    cleanup.push(path);
    return path;
};
try {
    const path0 = create();
    /* ... do something here */
    const path1 = create();
    /* ... do something ELSE here */
    const path2 = create();
    /* ... do something completely else here */
    const path3 = create();
    /* ... and here is another code block */
} finally {
    for (const path of cleanup) {
        try {
            fs.rmSync(path, { recursive: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error); // or something
        }
    }
}
```